# why so many folders in src ? Why does Android do it this way?

Tags: android

When I make an app with package name `com.example.app`,  `src/com/example/app/MainActivity.java` is created automatically. I am new to Java and I don't understand
why it uses so many folders inside folders? Why isn't it just `src/MainActivity.java`?

Comment: They are called "packages" and it's a very basic Java concept you need to familiarise yourself with.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid namespace collisions and conflicts, it's a common best practice in Java nest source code within a folder structure that is the reverse of the internet site associated with it. If everyone created jar library files in the root `/src` directory, eventually you'd have a collision and the code wouldn't be usable.

For instance, if I have some fancy Android library and I provided a class called Button, in a Button.java class, and you also at times wanted to use some other library that also had a Button.java in `/src`, your project would not compile.

Thus, in order to let everyone have their own unique Button class, the convention that was adopted was for everyone to use their reverse domain name, followed often by the project name. So the Facebook SDK, fo instance, has `/src/com/facebook/android/Util.java` while my own project has `/src/com/myapp/misc/Util.java` and I can use and reference both in my source code.